# Boost Include Files in VC++

Tags: boost, visual-c++, include

For the last few years, I have been exclusively a C# developer.  Previously, I developed in C++ and have a C++ application that I built about 3 years ago using VS2005.  It made extensive use of the Boost libraries.  I recently decided to brush off the old app and rebuild it in VS2008 with the latest version of Boost (the latest version with the "easy" installation program from BoostPro Computing), 1.39.  Previously when I had the program running I was at 1.33.  Also, the last time the program was running was at least 2 OS installations ago.  The Boost installation is located on my machine at: "C:\Program Files\boost\boost`_`1_39".  Anyway, I have done the following:

1. Set the project's "Additional Include Directories" directory to "C:\Program Files\boost\boost`_`1_39"
2. Added "C:\Program Files\boost\boost`_`1_39" to VS2008's Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - VC++ Directories - Include Files

I have a number of Boost includes in my stdafx.h file.  The compiler fails upon attempting to open the first one - #include `<`boost/algorithm/string/string.hpp`>`

I have confirmed that the above file is indeed located at "C:\Program Files\boost\boost`_`1_39\boost\algorithm\string\string.hpp"

I continue to get: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/algorithm/string/string.hpp': No such file or directory

**Any tips on what else to check would be greatly appreciated.**

Again, this is an application that compiled fine a few years ago, but the source has now been moved to a new machine/compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your .vcproj and .sln files in a plain text editor and do a search-and-replace on the old paths to correct them.   Much easier than digging through the IDE settings.